# Can a program override the commands of another program?

Tags: operating-system

For example, could a program stop another program from opening a website, or print a message. Or could a program override an os and change the names for everything (i.e. shutdown would be goodbye)?

Edit:
Thanks for clearing things up, i thought that a language low enough could make the computer do anything(like something in machine code).

Comment: Yes, depending upon what the operating system permits/allows, how it is structured, and how easy it is to subvert, all of those things may be possible.  Or are you asking with respect to feasibility on a _specific_ OS?

Comment: I think the distinction between what's possible and what's intended to be possible needs to be made here.  The key word in @aroth's reply was "subvert".

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's what a debugger does.  You may need some special support for kernel debugging to "override an OS" (often a second machine), but in general *anything* is possible in software. Do you have a more specific question?

Comment: Debuggers typically run code in a 'virtual' manner or are run on code that is specifically instrumented to interact with the debugger. Using a debugger to modify the memory state of an existing process that is not instrumented is not intended or easy.

Answer (score 0):

No.  The operating system prevents processes from modifying the memory space of other processes, for obvious security and stability reasons.

Comment: _Which_ operating system?  Or is your assertion that every conceivable operating system does this, and that all of them are always implemented in a way that does not allow this to be subverted under any circumstance?

Comment: Your right; I'm making an assumption about the OP's intended operating system family.  But I think I'm making a safe assumption :)

Comment: so if an os doesn't allow something, you cannot do it? it may be bc i dont know anything about operating systems, but i thought that if you program something in a language low enough you could make the computer do anything(i.e. in machine code or something similar), but thank you  for clearing things up.

Comment: like @aroth says, it's up to the operating system.  on linux or windows, for example, the os does its best to disallow applications from touching eachother.  if one process can successfully modify another process, it's generally considered a vulnerability.